# What method is called when spreading an object?

Tags: javascript

When using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) within an array literal declaration, the method on [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) is used:

```js
const o = {
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
      yield 1   
    },
}
console.log([...o]) // [ 1 ]
```

But when using the spread syntax for object properties, what method is used?

```js
const o = {
    p: 'this is p',
}
console.log({...o}) // { p: 'this is p' }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None, property spread is done by the JavaScript engine directly, there's no method on the object that gets used to do it.

Details in [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation); basically, evaluating property spread calls the abstract [CopyDataProperties](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-copydataproperties) operation, which only uses internal features (except that a host-provided exotic object [like a DOM object] could have a special definition of [[OwnPropertyKeys]], but it would affect all operations using that, not just spread).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any discussion to change this?

Comment: @Ben - I haven't heard any, but that doesn't meant there hasn't been. :-)

Comment: Relevant tweet thread: https://twitter.com/03d5d0a1/status/1234817807600300033